# Matrix for vector transformation

Tags: tensors

Say we have a matrix $L$ that maps vector components from an unprimed basis to a rotated primed basis according to the rule $x'_{i} = L_{ij} x_{j}$. $x'_i$ is the $i$th component in the primed basis and $x_{j}$ the $j$ th component in the original unprimed basis. Now $x'_{i} = \overline{e}'_i. \overline{x} = \overline{e}'_i. \overline{e}_j x_{j} $. Hence $L_{ij} = \overline{e}'_i. \overline{e}_j$. Thus the matrix equation relating the primed co-ordinate system to the unprimed one in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is

$$ \begin{pmatrix}x'_{1}\\ x'_{2}\\ x'_{3} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \overline{e}'_1. \overline{e}_1 & \overline{e}'_1. \overline{e}_2 & \overline{e}'_1. \overline{e}_3\\ \overline{e}'_2. \overline{e}_1 & \overline{e}'_2. \overline{e}_2 & \overline{e}'_2. \overline{e}_1 \\ \overline{e}'_3. \overline{e}_1 & \overline{e}'_3. \overline{e}_2 & \overline{e}'_3. \overline{e}_3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\ x_{3} \end{pmatrix} $$

Where the $\overline{e}'_i$s and $\overline{e}_j$s are unit basis vectors in the primed and unprimed co ordinate systems respectively.

Now I tried to apply the above idea to the following situation (Riley, Hobson and Bence Chapter 26, Problem 2).[image]

I took $\mathbf{A} = \overline{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{B} = \overline{e}_2$. It turns out that the matrix that transforms $\mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{A}' $ and $\mathbf{B} \rightarrow \mathbf{B}' $ is not the matrix that transforms the unprimed components to the primed components (that I used above) but the INVERSE (or transpose) of that matrix. I need to know where I am going wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found my mistake here. The $\overline{e'_{i}}$ refer to the *new* basis vectors (i.e. the basis vectors in the *rotated* frame) and *NOT* the components of the old basis vectors in the *rotated* frame. Hence we have:

$$ \overline{e'_{1}} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \overline{e'_{2}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \overline{e'_{3}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

in the *NEW* frame. Furthermore, to evaluate the dot products we need components in the same frame. Now we know the components of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ in the rotated frame. So, for example,

$$ L_{21}=\overline{e'_2}.\overline{e_1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}.\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{3} \\0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}  = 0$$.

and so on and so forth.